# How to give a consultant access into sharepoint

Tags: permissions, active-directory, security, access

I have a consultant joining into my company and unfortunately he will not have my company email address. Is there a way I can give him SharePoint access to the site on which he is going to work on? Since he is not on the active directory I was unable to provide him access.

Please help if there is any other through which we can provide him access. Since he need access to that site.

Comment: is it sharepoint online or Sharepoint on-prem?

Comment: It is Sharepoint 2010. Sorry for not mentioning that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010 you don't have this option "adding external user". but you have couple of options.

- simply add him into the active directory and grant him access.
- AD LDS is a feature of Windows Server.  While AD LDS itself is free, remember that your external users must have both Windows and SharePoint CALs. check this http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/12/configuring-ad-lds-with-sharepoint-2010.html
- Another option is Configure the Form based authentication and add that user.

In my opnion, for a single user except adding in the AD, all others required extra efforts and more work and maintenance.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I need to check with the tech to find if they can add him to the active directory, but basically i guess the answer must be no from them. I looked into the AD LDS steps, it is way complicated for just one users. Thanks for the effort on answer this.